# Eclipse build using maven

Tags: maven-2

I dont know if should ask the question on this forum. I am trying to download the sample from following URL http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/comment-page-1/#comment-76368. Once i download the zip and import the project into eclipse, how do i build it. I know eclipse builds it automatically, but here when i import it is giving errors like,  {Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"}. i think this has to do something with maven. So i installed the maven plugin into eclipse but still this error is present. Any clues?

Comment: How did you import it into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The zip referred above **is** a maven project.  Before trying to run it in Eclipse, you could try building it from the command-line after downloading and installing maven.  Once this is successful, and assuming you have the latest Eclipse with m2e plugin, you should be able to import this as a maven project.

Comment: i imported this maven project and tried to build it but get th following error
1/17/12 5:48:33 PM EST: Build error for /SpringMVC/pom.xml; org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3